# Azure diagnostics - is a custom performance counter necessary to get requests counters by url?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

I am aware that Requests\Sec, Requests Total etc. counters are available for free (they just need to be set up to be collected and transferred). Is anyone aware of any counters that are available which give some data based split by the http request url? So requests/sec for a specific url on the service? Just want to make sure there isn't anything before I head off writing custom per counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own.  I've helped do this for a customer who uses MVC framework.  It was super easy, as the only code needed to be instrumented was in the OnActionExecuting method for needed controllers.

Do make sure to instrument the creation of a custom performance counter definition via a startup script like described here (step #2):
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/performance-profiling/

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and write custom code :)

Here is a list of the performance counters available from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/04/01/list-of-performance-counters-for-windows-azure-web-roles.aspx:

> // .NET 3.5 counters
>
> @"\ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(**Total**)\Requests Total"
>
> @"\ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727(**Total**)\Requests/Sec"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Requests Queued"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Requests Rejected"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Request Execution Time"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v2.0.50727\Requests Queued"
>
> // Latest .NET Counters (4.0)
>
> @"\ASP.NET Applications(**Total**)\Requests Total"
>
> @"\ASP.NET Applications(**Total**)\Requests/Sec"
>
> @"\ASP.NET\Requests Queued"
>
> @"\ASP.NET\Requests Rejected"
>
> @"\ASP.NET\Request Execution Time"
>
> @"\ASP.NET\Requests Disconnected"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v4.0.30319\Requests Current"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v4.0.30319\Request Wait Time"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v4.0.30319\Requests Queued"
>
> @"\ASP.NET v4.0.30319\Requests Rejected"
>
> @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"
>
> @"\Memory\Available MBytes
>
> @"\Memory\Committed Bytes"
>
> @"\TCPv4\Connections Established"
>
> @"\TCPv4\Segments Sent/sec"
>
> @""\TCPv4\Connection Failures"
>
> @""\TCPv4\Connections Reset"
>
> @"\Network Interface(Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
>   _2)\Bytes Received/sec"
>
> @"\Network Interface(Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
>   _2)\Bytes Sent/sec"
>
> @"\Network Interface(Microsoft Virtual Machine Bus Network Adapter
>   _2)\Bytes Total/sec"
>
> @"\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Received/sec" @"\Network
>   Interface(*)\Bytes Sent/sec"
>
> @".NET CLR Memory(*Global*)\% Time in GC"

Comment: Right, I'm aware of these ones, looks like I've to write my own. I thought since the server must know what requests are coming in there might have been a way to surface this information.

Comment: @SkillM2 So I guess I answered your question?

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful as was Igorek's.